# Explicit isomorphism between $R[X]/(x^2+1)$ and $R[x]/(x^2+3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

The given question states that you have to proof that $\mathbb{R} [X]/(x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{R} [x]/(x^2+3)$ are isomorphic, and then give an explicit isomorphism between them.

I have already showed that are isomorphic, given that both rings are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

However i don't understand the second part (that is, giving the explicit isomorphism), which was given by our prof.

We construct two morphisms:

$\phi$ : $\mathbb{R} [X]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R} [X]$, and $\pi$ : $\mathbb{R} [X]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R} [X] / (x^3 + 3)$

given by $x \rightarrow \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} \rightarrow \frac{\overline{x}}{\sqrt{3}}$. Now, it can easily be seen that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, and that $\pi$ is exhaustive.

Now, i can't see why he states that ker($ \pi \circ \phi $)= ($x^2+1$).

When i "plug", for example, $x^2+1$, i evaluate the composition doing:

$x^2+1 \rightarrow \frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{3}} \rightarrow \frac{\overline{x^2+1}}{\sqrt{3}} \rightarrow \frac{\overline{-3+1}}{\sqrt{3}} \rightarrow \frac{\overline{-2}}{\sqrt{3}} $, which is not $\overline{0}$.

I searched from similar questions here, but i still can't understand this specific example. Did i misunderstood something in the way? Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: The map $\phi$ doesn't send any polynomial $f(x)$ to $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{3}}$. It sends specifically the element $x$ to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$, and the images of the other elements are determined by this. We have $\phi(x^2+1)=\phi(x)^2+\phi(1)=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})^2+1=\frac{x^2}{3}+1.$ And this is indeed a multiple of $x^2+3$.

Comment: Absolutely true I totally overlook it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Makes sense. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\phi$ doesn't send any polynomial $f(x)$ to $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{3}}$. It sends specifically the element $x$ to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$, and the images of the other elements are determined by this. We have:

$\phi(x^2+1)=\phi(x)^2+\phi(1)=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})^2+1=\frac{x^2}{3}+1,$

and this is indeed a multiple of $x^2+3$. This shows that $(x^2+1)\subseteq\ker(\pi\circ\phi)$. Since $(x^2+1)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, it follows that the two ideals are equal.